# MVC URI parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uri

Controller Action method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int key)
{
    CustomerContext customerContext = new CustomerContext();
    var customer = customerContext.Customers.Single(c => c.CustomerKey == key);
    return View(customer);
}
```

---

Registered Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Details",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{key}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", key = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

---

When I use this uri :

```
     http://localhost/Lab100_1/customer/details?key=11000
```

I get the proper customer details... however

When I use this uri :

```
 http://localhost/Lab100_1/customer/details/11000
```

I get this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'key' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'Lab100_1.Controllers.CustomerController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

---

What I already tried : 
in then route config:  defaults (passed a default value):

```
 new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", key = 0}
```

in the controller action method made the parameter nullable:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? key)
```

however I get the same error - I have a feeling if passing the parameter as query string works... then why passing it as URI parameter is not working...???  I have the route config in place... any help is much appreciated... thanks

Comment: can you please share complete route config cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your config is below the Default Route config. You should get it as **first priority than the default route**. So your route config should be like this -

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default1",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", key = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { key = @"\d+" } 
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Then it should work. **UPDATED: Use Constraint.**

Comment: @Ramiramilu... then it works... however what if I want the "Default" route to be the default route ?

Comment: Still it works!!! Try it out by going to /Home/Index/123 and also to /Home/Index?id=123, both works.

Comment: Yes it works... however what my point is -  eg: when I run the app I want the page : 'http://localhost/Lab100_1/Home/Default' to open first... but as the "Details" route is a priority one now... the application is trying to open that page on the initial run... i.e. 'http://localhost/Lab100_1/Customer/Details' and I don't want that...